# Is it necessary to load a view in every controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Because I thought of ajax posting my form to a specific function in my controller and do a sql-insert, but I want to stay on the same page. So is it necessary to load a view in the posted url (=destination)?

Comment: marko, if the answer I've provided is what you wanted, could you mark it as accepted? The same goes for the other questions you've asked – you should credit those who have helped you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's perfectly acceptable not to load a view and simply output the result of the operation. JSON encoding is ideal for this; see PHP's [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You could even create a view that outputs the JSON code if you're a purist, though there's no real need.